# Passing multiple variables to a view in laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, model-view-controller, view

I retrieved those from the database and assigned them to variables, but i am not able to pass both of them to the view.

```
$Posts = posts::find($id);

$image = images::find($id);
```

I tried passing them both in an array but haven't had luck.
tried this as well

```
return View::make('Index',['x_var' => $Posts, 'y_var' => $image]);
```

In the view it can only recognise the `x_var` and when i use the `y_var` the page crashes.

Answer (score 3):

You can use following...

```
return View::make('index', compact('Posts', 'image'));
```

Answer (score 1):

Or put it in a array like that..

```
$data = array(
   'Posts'  => posts::find($id),
   'image'   => images::find($id),
);

return View::make('Index')->with($data);
```

**Edit**

If you get an error with the `y_var` maybe there is a problem with the image you want to find. Please give us more information about the error.

Answer (score 1):

There are two ways you can do this:

The first way:

```
return View::make('view', ['Posts' => $posts, 'image', $image]);
```

And the second way, Which is for me, is much cleaner:

```
return View::make('view', compact('Posts', 'image'));
```

And please be consistent when you're coding.

It's really annoying to see a variable capitalized.

Comment: I worked at a PHP role for several years where the convention was to capitalise object variables, lower-case for everything else. Took me ages to unlearn it `;-)`.

Comment: Yeah, right now I'm learning Python. and I'm a PHP Developer. It is really hard to not use the braces for functions and classes. because I'm a PHP Developer.